# Splitting Multiple Columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the code I am currently working with.

```
df['RESULT_DATE'] = df['RESULT'] + " , " + df['DATE'].astype(str)
grouped=df.groupby('PID')['RESULT_DATE'].apply(list) 
gh=pd.DataFrame({'PID':grouped.index, 'RESULT_DATE':grouped.values})
vl=pd.DataFrame(gh.RESULT_DATE.values.tolist()).add_prefix('VL/DATE')
```

Running this code produces two strings separated by comma within the same column but I want these strings to be separated with two separate columns. So it would have "RESULT" and "DATE" as separated columns and there are 100 columns so looping through columns would be another possibility I think.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To split one column into two by a separator try this:

```
df['RESULT_DATE'].str.split(' , ', expand=True)
```

Comment: This would split within one column, but the datframe, I am working with have 100 columns, repeating with the pre-fix VL/DATE0, VL/DATE2, VL/DATE3..... all the up to VL/DATE100